# Objective-c. Fetching distinct values of attribute from core data

Tags: objective-c, core-data, attributes, entity

i have run into a problem that i can not solve. I have a "database" - read core data - where i have attribute that holds a value and level. 
Something like that
value -------- level
55 -------------4
33 -------------4
50 -------------5
70 -------------6
44 -------------5

what i want now is a to extract all values from level 5 only and add them together. How can i achieve this ?I did found "fetch distinct values" on apple dev site, but this would apply to extracting all values from one attribute.

Help appreciated, thank you. If i have missed a similar topic then please provide me with a link. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following fetch request:

```
// Fetch request for your entity:
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Entity"];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];

// Restrict result to "level == 5":
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"level == %d", 5];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

// Expression description for "@sum.value":
NSExpression *sumExpression = [NSExpression expressionForKeyPath:@"@sum.value"];
NSExpressionDescription *expressionDescription = [[NSExpressionDescription alloc] init];
[expressionDescription setName:@"sumValue"];
[expressionDescription setExpression:sumExpression];
[expressionDescription setExpressionResultType:NSInteger32AttributeType];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[expressionDescription]];

NSArray *result = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

The result for your data is

```
(
    {
        sumValue = 94;
    }
)
```

i.e. an array containing one dictionary with the sum of values with level=5.